# Unable to unmarshal array field in golang

Tags: go, struct, yaml, unmarshalling

I am trying to unmasrhal the following `flux` `HelmRelease` file.

```
apiVersion: helm.fluxcd.io/v1
kind: HelmRelease
metadata:
  annotations:
    fluxcd.io/automated: 'false'
    fluxcd.io/tag.ats: glob:*
  name: ats
  namespace: myns
spec:
  chart:
    git: git@github.com:reponame/project.git
    path: charts/path1/path1/myapp
    ref: master
  releaseName: foobar
  values:
    allowAllEgress: true
    recycleApp: true
    hooks:
      slackChannel: https://hooks.slack.com/services/something/somethingelse/
```

Here are my models

```
type HelmReleaseValues struct {
    AllowAllEgress bool `yaml:"allowAllEgress"`
    RecycleApp     bool `yaml:"recycleApp"`
    Hooks          `yaml:"hooks"`
}

type Hooks struct {
    SlackChannel string `yaml:"slackChannel"`
}

type Values struct {
    HelmReleaseValues `yaml:"values"`
    ReleaseName       string `yaml:"releaseName"`
    Chart             `yaml:"chart"`
}

type Spec struct {
    Values `yaml:"spec"`
}
```

The problem is that the fields `allowAllEgress` and `recycleApp` are getting unmarshalled.

However the `Hooks` field in my struct turns out to be empty.

What am I doing wrong in the struct modelling / tagging?

**edit**: here is my code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"

    "github.com/davecgh/go-spew/spew"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
)

const ExitCodeCmdErr = 1

func main() {
    rawYaml := parseHelmReleaseFile("myfile.yaml")
    spew.Dump(rawYaml)
}

func parseHelmReleaseFile(fileName string) Spec {

    var v Spec

    yamlFile, err := ioutil.ReadFile(fileName)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("yaml file err   #%v ", err)
        os.Exit(ExitCodeCmdErr)
    }

    err = yaml.Unmarshal(yamlFile, &v)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Unmarshal: %v", err)
        os.Exit(ExitCodeCmdErr)
    }

    return v
}
```

I am running the program and grepping for the output (the actual helm release file is huge)

```
▶ go clean && gb .             
~/Desktop/yamltutorial
./foobar | grep -i hooks -A 3
--
   Hooks: (main.Hooks) {
    SlackChannel: (string) ""
   }
  },
```

Comment: Can you share code that actually reproduces the problem? Because what you have there seems to work just fine: https://play.golang.org/p/ExF4tWirDKB

Comment: thanks, check my update

Answer (score 2):

You did not have Chart struct

```
type Chart struct {
    Git  string `yaml:"git"`
    Path string `yaml:"path"`
    Ref  string `yaml:"ref"`
}
```

Added that and got the following output

```
{Values:{HelmReleaseValues:{AllowAllEgress:true RecycleApp:true Hooks:{SlackChannel:https://hooks.slack.com/services/something/somethingelse/}} ReleaseName:foobar Chart:{Git:git@github.com:reponame/project.git Path:charts/path1/path1/myapp Ref:master}}}
```

Playground file with complete code.

https://play.golang.org/p/vCnjApr6gI9